# posix compliant だと思っている sed コマンドが linux と mac で挙動が違う

Tags: macos, sh, sed, posix

redis-cli を用いて、今現在の redis の config 情報を yaml で出力しようと思いました。

```
redis-cli config get '*' | sed -e $'N;s/\\\n\\(.*\\)/: "\\1"/'
```

redis-cli は「設定項目」「その値」が交互に続く形で出力を行うので、それを、上記のように sed で yaml 形式に整形しようと考えました。

これは、 linux サーバーで実行すると、問題なく実行されます。一方、手元の mac で実行すると、以下のエラーを出力します。

```
$ redis-cli config get '*' | sed -e $'N;s/\\\n\\(.*\\)/: "\\1"/'
sed: 1: "N;s/\
\(.*\)/: "\1"/
": unterminated substitute pattern
```

#### 質問

- Mac の sed で上記の sed script がエラーになるのはなぜですか？

#### (追記) バージョン情報

- linux 上: `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`
- mac: 確認方法がわからないですが、 `man sed` によると以下が書いてあります。

  - ``` The sed utility is expected to be a superset of the IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'') specification. ```
  - man ページの末尾の日付: `May 10, 2005`

Comment: `sed`コマンドのバージョンはそれぞれ分かりますか？

Comment: @cubick mac の sed のバージョンはわかりませんたが、わかるところを追記しました。

Comment: 試せるmacの環境が無いのでコメントに留めますが、エラーメッセージで検索すると関連しそうな記事が見つかりました - [Mac等BSD系sedだと変換後に改行を出すのが一筋縄ではいかない、と言う話](https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2014/09/21/computer-bash/)

Comment: 全て解決した後で気づいたこと: ANSI-C Quoting は POSIX sh には含まれないので、もし、改行を含んだ argument をコマンドに渡したい場合は、 printf を使っての command substitution をやると良さそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

問題が判明したので、自己回答します。

posix sed での s 式は、次の形式です。

> [2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags

ここで、`\`の直後に改行文字を入力することが適切なのは、 replacement の中だけです。自分は、 BRE の中でそれをやろうとしていました。

なので、今回のスクリプトは、以下のようにすると posix compliant になります。

```
redis-cli config get '*' | sed -e 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/: "\1"/'
```

#### 参考

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html